# Communication to Content script fails. Google chrome extension application

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, content-script

i am new to Javascript and am trying to implement a google chrome extension. I read the instructions (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted), but still I have some troubles with my code.

I have got a popup menu with buttons and I want to get back the DOM content of the current page when a button is clicked.

Therefore i created a contentscript.js and a popup.js. The popup.js asks the contentscript to get the DOM (still needs to be implemented how I do that) and send back the DOM.

I receive the error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

This is my code:

popup.js

```
var ads = ["increase", "reduce", "blabla"];

function markAds(text) {
document.getElementById("markAd").innerHTML=ads[0];
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true},   function(tabs) {
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
  alert(response.farewell);
  });
});
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var markAd = document.getElementById('markAd');
 // onClick's logic below:
 markAd.addEventListener('click', function() {
     markAds();
    });
});
```

mainfest.js

```
{
"name": "Test",
"description": "Test Description",
"version": "0.7",
"permissions": ["contextMenus","activeTab"],
"content_scripts": [{
"matches": ["<all_urls>"],
"js": ["contentscript.js"]
}],
"browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.greeting == "hello")
  sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem that this code will produce that error, you've probably modified the source and didn't refresh the extension.

Comment: I both refreshed it, deleted it entirely and uploaded it again several times but i keep getting that error and i don't see why

Comment: What tab do you have opened when you press the `#markAd` button ? I guess this could happen if you have focused a tab that doesn't contain the content script (a chrome tab, something like `chrome://settings`)

Comment: thanks @Titus. you are right. I tried it directly at the chrome settings page! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help. Good luck!